# How to copy 2 text boxes into 1 using CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, text, input

I've got 2 text inputs, 'First_Name' And 'Last_Name'.

I have a 3rd text box that I want to display the whole name, i.e. 'First_Name Last Name'.

So far I've worked out how to copy text from one box to another -

```css
<script>
$('#TextBox1').blur(function() {
var sourceElement = document.getElementById("TextBox1");
var targetElement = document.getElementById("TextBox2");

targetElement.value = sourceElement.value;
});
</script>
```

But I don't know I would do TextBox1 + TextBox2 = TextBox3?

Comment: You should also add your HTML into the code snippet.

Comment: Always provide your full code in order to SO users to understand better your issue and come with a good solution.

Comment: Do your mean: `The3rdText = sourceElement + " " + targetElement`

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I'm using webflow so I don't have access to the html, only the custom css. In the code above, I'm copying the value from one text box to another; what I'm trying to do is copy text from two text boxes into one.

I imagine I'd want to have sourceElement1 + sourceElement2 = targetElement?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to have dynamic user interaction using CSS, you would need JavaScript. An example of what you described would be:

```
$('input[type=text]').blur(function() {
    var full = $("#First_Name").val() + ' ' + $("#Last_Name").val();
    $("#TextBoxFull").val(full);
});
```

This means, anytime a text input is blurred, take the first name, a space, and the last name, and set that as the value of the third input

Comment: I've tried using your code as provided, and in the third '#TextBoxFull' input I get a value of '[object Object] [object Object]' as soon as any text is entered into the first two boxes...

Comment: @DavidJames Oops. I made a typo. I just concatenated the jQuery objects, and not their values. Try again with the revised